# colorWithPatternImage with iPhone 4 Retina Display (image@2x.png)

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uicolor, iphone-4

Thanks to SO's search function blowing up whenever I enter "@2x", it's difficult to tell whether this has already been asked...

I've been using colorWithPatternImage: to build tiled background images for my various views.  However, these predictably look like trash when viewed on the new iPhone 4 display.  So I've built @2x versions of my tile.png files, yet colorWithPatternImage: evidently can't properly handle UIImages with double the scale.

Has anyone effectively developed a workaround for this issue?  Perhaps within the CoreGraphics framework (of which, I'm quite the novice)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a bug with the SDK. `colorWithPatternImage:` is doing strange things with the HD image. There's a small [thread on the Apple Dev Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/273001) on it, but basically I think it's a bug. Not sure if Apple are aware of it just yet.

I've worked around it by drawing the pattern in a subclass of the view within `-drawRect:`.

Hope this helps.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIImage themeImageNamed:@"UIBackgroundPattern.png"] drawAsPatternInRect:rect];
}
```