# Lines separating UIView tiled background images

Tags: ios, uiview

I tried to fill a UIView with tiled background images.

The size of the UIView is 1136 * 640, and the size of the background image I use is 64 * 64.

The code I write is:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"paper_texture.png"]];
```

But after I set the background image for this view, there are lines that separate each tiled background image.

I tested this using css repeating background image in html, and there are no such lines.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624723/colorwithpatternimage-creates-black-grids-in-iphone-4   a couple possible solutions there

Comment: Have you verified that the image itself doesn't have a border?  Have you extra double verified it?  Can you show us the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem:

1. Open this image in Photoshop
2. Select all and copy it to clipboard
3. Create a new file in Photoshop. Set this new file as follows:
   a. The same dimension as the image
   b. RGB and 8bit depth with 72 pixels/inch
   c. White background
4. Paste the image I copied in step 2 to this new file.
5. Save this file and use the new image

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Retina-resolution @2x version of your image? If so, remove the `.png` from the image name and iOS will load the correct version. If you are loading the wrong image, perhaps loading the correct one will get rid of the lines.

Comment: I have a Retina-resolution image. I removed the .png from the image name, but the separating lines are still there :(